# Ergodicity of linear dynamical systems and convergence of covariance matrices

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, ds.dynamical-systems, stochastic-processes, ergodic-theory

Let $z(n+1)=Bz(n)+\xi(n+1)$ be an $N$-dimensional linear dynamical system with $\left(\xi(n)\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ being i.i.d. with $\xi(n)\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\Sigma_{\xi})$.

**Assumptions:** a) The covariance matrix $\Sigma_{\xi}$ is full-rank (so that the support of the distribution of $\xi(n)$ is absolutely continuous w.r.t. Lebesgue); b) $\xi\left(n+1\right)$ is independent of $z(n)$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$; c) the dynamical system is stable, i.e., the spectral radius of the matrix $B\in\mathbb{R}^{N\times N}$ is smaller than $1$, $\rho(B)<1$; d) the process $\left(z(n)\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is initialized at the invariant distribution.

Define $R_k\overset{\Delta}=\mathbb{E}\left[z(n+k)z(n)^{\top}\right]$ as the $k$-lag moment associated with the process $\left(z(n)\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$.

Define its empirical counterpart: $\widehat{R}_k(m)=\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m z(i+k)z(i)^{\top}$.

**Question.[Strong law]** Is it true that under the discussed assumptions, we have

$$\widehat{R}_k(m)\overset{m\rightarrow \infty}\longrightarrow R_k,$$

for all $k<\infty$, almost surely?

Under these assumptions, the process $\left(z(n)\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is geometrically ergodic -- in particular, its distribution converges to the invariant distribution w.r.t. the total variation norm.

A full proof or any reference would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Something's wrong, the terms in the defining sum of $\hat R_k(m)$ do not depend on $i$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @JochenWengenroth, corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Under your assumptions, the following facts are true:
\begin{equation*}
      \lim_{m\to\infty}\hat{R}_k(m)=R_k, \qquad \forall k\in \mathbb{N}_+, \quad \text{a.s.}, \tag{1}
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
    \hat{R}_k(m)=\frac1m\sum_{i=1}^{m}z(i+k)z(i)^\top, \qquad \forall k,m\in \mathbb{R}_+.
\end{equation*}
From your Assumption d), the intial distribution of $z$ is same as the distribution
of
\begin{equation*}
    z(0)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty B^n\xi(-n).
\end{equation*}
If taking $z(0)$ as initial value for linear dynamic system  $z(n+1)=Bz(n)+\xi(n+1)$, then
\begin{equation*}
    z(i) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty B^n\xi(i-n),\quad i\ge0,
\end{equation*}
hence $z=\{z(i), i\ge 0\}$ is ergodic stationary Gaussian Process. For each $k\in\mathbb{N}_+$, the
\begin{equation*}
    y(i)=z(i+k)z(i)^\top, \quad i\in \mathbb{N}_+
\end{equation*}
is also an ergodic stationary matrix-valued($\mathbb{R}^{N\times N}$-valued) process and
\begin{equation*}
    \hat{R}_k(m)=\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^{m}y(i).
\end{equation*}
Therefore, using ergodicity of $y=\{y(i),i\in\mathbb{N}_+\}$, (1) is true.

**Remark**  The following statements come from J. L. Doob, *Stochastic processes,* John Wiley & Sons, 1953. Ch X, $\S$1, pp452--.

In brief, the ergodicity belong to mearsure-preseving transformation $T$ defined by
\begin{equation*}
    T\xi(i)=\xi(i+1), \quad \forall i\in \mathbb{N}_+. \tag{R1}
\end{equation*}
From (R1),
\begin{align*}
    Tz(i) & =z(i+1), \\
    Ty(i) & =y(i+1). 
\end{align*}
The ergodicity of $\xi=\{\xi(i),i\in \mathbb{N}_+ \}$ is the ergodicity  of $T$,
which also guarantee the ergodicity of $z,y$.

Comment: JGWang, thank you. Yes, the process is ergodic (and its sample mean converge almost surely). More concretely, my question is how to prove (or specific reference) that the empirical lag-moments converge almost surely to the limit covariances. Thanks again.

Comment: @AugustoSantos Thank you for your reply. I rewrite last several lines. Welcome to propose any question about this post.

Comment: JGWang, why is $(y(i))_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ ergodic?

Comment: @AugustoSantos Please see the added Remark.

Comment: I do not have the book with me, but I believe the map $T$ that you are referring to is the (one-lag) time shift map (which is ergodic, indeed)? I see, let me think about (+1 upvote).

Comment: Thank you  for your upvote. Also, you are right, map $T$ is ergodic.

Comment: Just to confirm: The idea would be to resort to Birkhoff's Theorem to establish convergence, correct? Remark that $T$ maps sample paths into sample paths (endowed with the product Lebesgue). If we choose $\pi_t$ to be the projection map, it returns the value of the process at time $t$, then Birkhoff's would imply $(1/n)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \pi_t(T^k (w)) \overset{a.s.}\longrightarrow \int \pi_t d\mu = 0$, where $w$ is a centered process whose distribution is kept invariant under the shift $T$ and $\mu$ is Lebesgue. Is that the idea?

Comment: In my post, the $T$ defined by (R1) is ergodic, than for all measurable(and integrable) functional,  $\pi_t$ of $\xi$, $(1/n)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\pi_t(T^k(\xi))\to\int\pi_t(\xi)d\mu$.

Comment: In my post, the $T$ defined by (R1) is ergodic, than for all measurable(and integrable) functional,  $\pi_t$ of $\xi$, $(1/n)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\pi_t(T^k(\xi))\to\int\pi_t(\xi)d\mu$ is ture. By the way, if you have other problem, you could give a new post, because it is not convenient discussion here.